# Select first row in groupby meeting condition with diff

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to select the first occurrence/row meeting a condition with `diff()` for each group in a groupby.

At first, I figured I would want to use a filter here, as I want to cut down the result of the groupby. Right now I'm trying this:

```
df_slice.groupby('SeqNum').filter(lambda x: x.A.diff() <= -1).first()
```

which results in:

```
{TypeError}filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool
```

From the error, I get that diff is returning a series, and it expects a scalar, but I'm not sure how to reform the statement to get what I want, which is the first occurrence/row of each group meeting the diff criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `drop_duplicate`

```
df_slice[df_slice.groupby('SeqNum').apply(lambda x: (x.A.diff() <= -1)).sort_index(level=1).values].drop_duplicates('SeqNum')
```

Comment: Can you explain what the double lambda is doing? I'm a bit confused about that.

Comment: Hmm... this returns {ValueError}Item wrong length 177440 instead of 298860. 298860 is the length of my df_slice.

Comment: @John can you provide toy data ?

Comment: I figured the issue out. I forgot some of the SeqNum instances are null, so I just added a df_slice[df_slice.SeqNum.notnull()] slice, and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

**select min(id) keep(dense_rank first order by kind) id
     , val
     , min(kind) kind
  from mytable
 group by val;
ID |  VAL | KIND
-: | ---: | ---:
 3 |    3 |    4
 2 | 1337 |    1**